# Don't Search Attachments in Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-scope, fast-search, fast

I want my scope to not search in attachments that list item has.
I have a scope which is searching in a list and displaying some of it's column.
But when we search it's searching in attachments also which is not desired.
Can i configure something in my scope. I am using one scope also?
I am using Fast Search.

Thanks